# Thermal Contact resistance due to adhesive

Tags: thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

Let us assume two metal plates attached with each other by an adhesive layer. Now when we try to evaluate the total heat resistance of the whole setup, will the thermal contact resistance due to adhesive come in series with the other resistances or should it taken to be in parallel to each of the metal plates in an equivalent resistance circuit?

Also it would be great if someone just corrects any errors in my question statement.

Comment: Or do we even need to consider the contact resistance while calculating the total resistance?

Comment: Which way is the heat flowing - across the layer are perpendicular to the layer?

Comment: Perpendicular. So both the resistances due to the metal plates are already in series without considering the adhesive.

Comment: In parallel, not series, right?

Comment: I mean they both are at different temperature gradients. Heat flows perpendicular to the plane of joining of plates